# Socket Programming Chat System

Tags: php, android

I have created a chat system for android using socket programming, the system works fine when the two or more devices are in the same WiFi/network, but when I off the WiFi and switch on mobile data on one device that device doesn't receive messages. Can someone help me solve this problem.

```
static final int SocketServerPORT = 8181;
LinearLayout loginPanel, chatPanel;

Button buttonSend;
String msgLog = "";
ChatClientThread chatClientThread = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cliyent);


    loginPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginpanel);
    chatPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chatpanel);



    buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}



OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String ip ="192.168.1.10";
        chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread("Dhanushka", ip, SocketServerPORT);
        chatClientThread.start();


        System.out.println("plz givme curent location");
        chatClientThread.sendMsg("plz givme curent location " + "\n");

    }

};



private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {

    String name;
    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;

    String msgToSend = "";
    boolean goOut = false;

    ChatClientThread(String name, String address, int port) {
        this.name = name;
        dstAddress = address;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(name);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

            while (!goOut) {
                if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                    msgLog += dataInputStream.readUTF();

                    Cliyent.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("msgLog"+msgLog);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    msgToSend = "";
                }
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            final String eString = e.toString();
            Cliyent.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Cliyent.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            final String eString = e.toString();
            Cliyent.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Cliyent.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Cliyent.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                }

            });
        }

    }

    private void sendMsg(String msg){
        msgToSend = msg;
    }
}
}
```

---

Sever part

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;

TextView infoIp, infoPort, chatMsg;

String msgLog = "";

List<ChatClient> userList;

ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    infoIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
    infoPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoport);
    chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);

    infoIp.setText(getIpAddress());

    userList = new ArrayList<ChatClient>();

    ChatServerThread chatServerThread = new ChatServerThread();
    chatServerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class ChatServerThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    infoPort.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                }
            });

            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
                userList.add(client);
                ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(client, socket);
                connectThread.start();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;
    ChatClient connectClient;
    String msgToSend = "";

    ConnectThread(ChatClient client, Socket socket){
        connectClient = client;
        this.socket= socket;
        client.socket = socket;
        client.chatThread = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

        try {
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String n = dataInputStream.readUTF();

            connectClient.name = n;

            msgLog += connectClient.name + " connected@" + connectClient.socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + connectClient.socket.getPort() + "\n";
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                  //  chatMsg.setText(msgLog);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(msgLog);

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage(msgLog)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Available",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {



                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Curent Location",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome " + n + "\n");
            dataOutputStream.flush();

            broadcastMsg(n + " join our chat.\n");

            while (true) {
                if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                    String newMsg = dataInputStream.readUTF();


                    msgLog += n + ": " + newMsg;
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                        }
                    });

                    broadcastMsg(n + ": " + newMsg);
                }

                if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    msgToSend = "";
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            userList.remove(connectClient);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            connectClient.name + " removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    msgLog += "-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n";
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                        }
                    });

                    broadcastMsg("-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private void sendMsg(String msg){
        msgToSend = msg;
    }

}

private void broadcastMsg(String msg){
    for(int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++){
        userList.get(i).chatThread.sendMsg(msg);
        msgLog += "- send to " + userList.get(i).name + "\n";
    }

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
        }
    });
}

private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }

    return ip;
}

class ChatClient {
    String name;
    Socket socket;
    ConnectThread chatThread;

}
}
```

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: can you send your email

Comment: it doesn't because you are sending it locally. if you want to recieve/send externally then you must have a public ip and have it port forwarded on your chat servers local ip so clients can send through the public ip instead of the local ip of the chat server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If client part using mobile network you have to routing your modem you can not use 192.168.1.10 anymore and otherwise if server with mobile network you have to change ip with new one

Comment: can you explain it bit more please. Or any examples?

Comment: String ip ="192.168.1.10"; this is only works for same wetwork. When your server phone not in the same wifi anymore you have the learn your new ip adress and update the string ip in client.when you close or open wifi your ip changes